# On filtering Table using Keyup Jquery, results alignment is improper

Tags: jquery

I am using KeyuP on a text field , the functionaity works fine , but the results **alignment** is improper

In the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/255/

Enter the keyword t

https://unsee.cc/nadiperu/

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
      $('#searchinputtext').keyup(function ()
        {
               $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
             var noElemtag = true;

                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#videosfromtagstable tbody td');

                el = tr.filter(function() {
                    return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val)>=0;
                }).closest('td');

                if(el.length>=1)
                {
                  noElemtag  = false;
                }


                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();

         if (noElemtag)
    $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/256/ to search over rows

**UPDATE**: or http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/257/ to search over first cell on each table row.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#searchinputtext').keyup(function ()
        {
                    $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
                 var noElemtag = true;

                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#videosfromtagstable tbody tr');//use tr not td

                el = tr.filter(function() {
                    return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val)>=0;
                });// <==== closest("tr") removed

                if(el.length>=1)
                {
                    noElemtag  = false;
                }

                //now you fadeIn/Out every row not every cell
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();

            if (noElemtag)
    $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
        })
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you @UnKnown :)

Answer (score 1):

replace css property display to visibility

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#searchinputtext').keyup(function ()
        {
           $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
           var noElemtag = true;

                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#videosfromtagstable tbody td');
                
                el = tr.filter(function() {
                    return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val)>=0;
                }).closest('td');

                if(el.length>=1)
                {
                 noElemtag  = false;
                }
                tr.not(el).css('visibility','hidden')
          
                el.css('visibility','visible')

   if (noElemtag)
    $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
        })
});
```

```css
#errmsgnotags
{
 color: red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchinputtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<span id="errmsgnotags"></span>
<table class="mytable1 table" id="videosfromtagstable">
   <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Video</th>
      </tr>
      <tr video-id="48" class="newvideos">
         <td>Dsada</td>
         <td><a href="http://xxx/Images/dfimage.jpg" target="_blank">http://xxx/Images/dfimage.jpg</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr video-id="58" class="newvideos">
         <td>Test</td>
         <td><a href="http://xxx/Images/dfimage.jpg" target="_blank">http://xxx/Images/dfimage.jpg</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr video-id="59" class="newvideos">
         <td>Fdfsd</td>
         <td><a href="http://xxx/Images/dfimage.jpg" target="_blank">http://xxx/Images/dfimage.jpg</a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks but this hiding the second column know ? for example if you type te